# Trapezoid inside side is less than small base

Tags: geometry

[image: trapezoid]

In the trapezoid $ABCD$, $AB = 15$, $CD = 12$, $AD = 9$ and $BC = 10$. Now, the height $h$ is $8.84$. Now let us draw perpendicular to $AB$ from $E$, $EG$, where $EG = 4.42$ and draw a line $EF$ parallel. Now, $AE = 4.5$ and $BF = 5$ as $\triangle AEG$ and $\triangle ADG$ are similar. Now applying Pythagoras we get,
$$AG^2 + GE^2 = AE^2$$ or $$AG^2 = (4.5)^2 - ( 4.42)^2$$ or $$AG = 0.844$$ and similarly, $BH = 2.33$.

So, we get $EF = AB - AG - BH = 15-2.33-0.844 = 11.826$. But , $EF$ must be greater than $DC$, but calculating I have got the wrong thing. Which calculation did I do wrong? and what should I do to correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data are incompatible with the figure. There is no trapezoid $ABCD$ such that $AB=15$, $BC=10$, $CD=12$, $DA=9$ and it has the format sketched in the figure below:

See the calculations:

[image]

The correct figure is:

[image]

If you consider that new figure and do your calculations, you'll get the right answer.